# Heroku cannot detect the buildpack - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy my web service on Heroku which is a Spring Boot project (Java) and its gives me the following error when I try to push to Heroku:

```
Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

I tried using the custom build pack of Java but it still doesn't work. Does anybody have any idea on how I can fix this. Any help would be really appreciated.

I also have jetty-runner dependency and plugin. I also created a Procfile which is defined as the following:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

My directory for the project is as follows (I don't know if this matters):

```
-root
  |___projectDirectory
  |        |____code...
  |        |____Procfile
  |___readme
```

Comment: does your application have a `pom.xml` file in the root directory? If Heroku doesn't find one, it will give you the `no Cedar-supported app detected` error.

Comment: also, the `Procfile` needs to go in the root directory.

Comment: @codefinger Okay so now I put everything in the root directory but the target folder is empty, it doesn't have the pom.xml or pom.properties. Is that normal for spring boot projects. Because it gives me the error that its unable to access the jetty-runner jar file in target/dependency. I think that has to do with my target folder being empty. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had, I believe, the same problem and it was caused by my git root directory not being the same as your project root. This was also my project structure:

```
-gitRoot
  |___projectDirectory
           |____code...
           |____Procfile
           |____pom.xml
```

Because we are using `git push heroku master` or similar, Heroku (upon receiving our project) assumes that the root directory of git is the root directory of the project. It then looks in `gitRoot` for the `pom.xml` and the `Procfile`. When it doesn't find them, you see our familiar error.

I simply moved my `.git` folder and `.gitignore` file into the `projectDirectory` and ran:

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "Move the git root down to project root."
mvn clean install
git push heroku master
```

That worked a treat, but don't forget to update your `.gitignore` file and clear the cache before committing next. The new project structure looked like this.

```
projectDirectory
           |____code...
           |____Procfile
           |____pom.xml
```

In the above the `projectDirectory` is also the git root directory.

I hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your need your war file and pom.xml in one directory and it worked.
Used dropbox to deploy

[image]