# Heroku: No default language could be detected for this app for python even with runtime.txt

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, python-3.5

I am trying to deploy a [project](https://github.com/rakeshsukla53/sukoon/tree/master/src) to heroku and I am getting this error:-

```
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 17.36 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 23), reused 3 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:             HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

If you go to my github [project](https://github.com/rakeshsukla53/sukoon/tree/master/src), I have everything required for the heroku project including `runtime.txt` file but still I am getting this error. I tried changing different python versions supported by Heroku but still same error. Could anyone help me out ?

If I add a buildpack then I am getting the following error

```
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 17.36 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 23), reused 3 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz buildpack
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Not sure where I am going wrong ?

Comment: See also [Heroku Python failed to detect app matching buildpack - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228526/heroku-python-failed-to-detect-app-matching-buildpack) // [python - Heroku buildpack error while pushing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840472/heroku-buildpack-error-while-pushing/49840654#49840654) // [django - Heroku: No default language could be detected for this app for python even with runtime.txt - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232967/heroku-no-default-language-could-be-detected-for-this-app-for-python-even-with)

Comment: Similar questions: for [Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46462019/5267751), [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362014/5267751), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31465992/5267751), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44232967/5267751)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution to this problem can be specifying the buildpack during app creation like :

```
$ heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/python
```

or after app creation like:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Refer Docs : [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application)

The other problem I figured was that I had unnecessary `package.json` and other files in my django project. I solved it by removing unnecessary files from my app directory.
Since these files were obstructing the automatic detection of buildpack.

Another reason of failed detection could be **wrong folder structure** of your app. The `Procfile` and other heroku files should be right at the start of the git directory otherwise your app won't get detected.

Comment: This gives me `App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
`

Answer (score 1):

1. in your git bash : `echo "python-3.7.0" > runtime.txt` (adds runtime.txt file in your root directory with instructions to use python v3.7.0 by Heroku)
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -am "another commit"`
4. `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

As for the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#expected-files-for-python):

Heroku automatically identifies your app as a Python app if any of the following files are present in its root directory:

- `requirements.txt`
- `setup.py`
- `Pipfile`

You can solve that with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, for example.